# What is the correct term for a hash' key value pair?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm taking notes on RoR to improve my understanding, and I'm fed up of constantly having to write 'key and value pair' when referring to a hash "element."

What's the correct term for 'key and value pair'. Is it a "hash element"?

Should I refer to

```
[:system_message => "Hello"]
```

as the **:system_message hash element**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, It is a `hash entry`. Every Key-Value pair is termed as a **hash entry**.

You cannot say `flash[:system_message => "Hello"]` as the :system_message hash element. But, you can say that flash is hash variable containing only one entry with **key** as `:system_message` and **value** as `Hello`.

Refer http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Hash.html for more info.

Answer (score 1):

Its usually called "hash entry"

See http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Hash.html the new method.

Comment: Thanks, it's a trivial point but if I'm going to write it a million times I might as well write the right thing!